# Access, Select Case ActiveControl.Name?

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, controls, select-case

i have 2 combo boxes (`c1`, `c2`) in a form access, with button **Search** , if a user choose a value from `c1` and click on **Search** it should open a `FORM1`, and if the user choose a value from `c2` and click on Search it should open `FORM2`.

```
Private Sub Commande6_Click()
    Select Case ActiveControl.Name
        Case "c1"
            DoCmd.OpenForm "FORM1"
        Case "c2"
            DoCmd.OpenForm "FORM2"
        Case Else
            'traitement
     End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: why doesn't it work?

Comment: i don't know , when i click on the button its doesn't show me anything

Comment: Add a temporary line at the start of that procedure: `MsgBox ActiveControl.Name`. Then try the variations and see what ***it*** thinks the active control is called. The solution should become pretty obvious.  (I bet the active control is the Search button, since that was the last think clicked..  It's not called `2nd-to-last-ActiveControl` :)

Comment: it shows me 'Commande6'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're clicking a combo box and then clicking your <kbd>Search</kbd> button, the a combo box wasn't the last thing click, so it's not Active - the Search button is  (`Commande6` in your case)

```
Public lastCBclicked as String

Private Sub c1_Click()
    lastCBclicked  = ActiveControl.Name
End Sub

Private Sub c2_Click()
    lastCBclicked  = ActiveControl.Name
End Sub

Private Sub Commande6_Click()
  Select Case lastCBclicked  
    Case "c1"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "FORM1"
    Case "c2"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "FORM2"
    Case Else
        'traitement
   End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, or a variable. :)

Comment: While I would recommend this approach (that's why I'm not posting this as an answer), you do have `Screen.PreviousControl` for the previous control. However, this answer also works if you've clicked another control (not `c1` nor `c2` in between, while `Screen.PreviousControl` doesn't)

Comment: it wooooorks thaaank youuuuu

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth is it possible to put 2 conditon in one Case ??

Answer (score 0):

Using ActiveControl won’t work. When you click search, control goes to the search button.

You can handle in a couple ways. You could (a) query both controls to detect which one is not set to the default, or (b) keep track of which one last had focus (using a hidden control, maybe).

EDIT: See ashleydawgs answer for the code.